# Is there a way to see the source code for string methods?

Tags: python, built-in

I'm trying to see source code for python's build in functions like `str.lower()` or `str.lstrip()`. I was trying `inspect.getsource()` but this didn't work. Is there any other way to view source codes for built ins?

Comment: I always found a tad difficult finding information about the details of the C implementation of Python's basic types. Regular IDEs won't do a good job because they're coded in C, and they've been compiled (so there's no _source_) It takes some googling in a per-case basis... http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/ You have the repository with the source code here: https://www.python.org/downloads/source/

Comment: What version of Python? What bitness (x86, x86-64?)

Comment: `inspect` won't work because the source code for those methods **isn't in Python**. Why do you want to see it?